# How to set up auto sync secondary MySQL server without changing IP

Tags: mysql, load-balancing

Currently, I've 2 DB servers say, public 123.123.123.123 IP mapped to one of the servers 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3

Anyone has an idea how to set up auto sync of both MySQL server.
And  192.168.1.2 is down, it will fallback to 192.168.1.3 with 123.123.123.123 mapped to it automatically without the need of manual configuration ?

Anyone has useful information to go towards this direction?

Comment: First google result for "mysql load balancing": http://www.howtoforge.com/loadbalanced_mysql_cluster_debian

Comment: Offtopic - not a programming question. Should be on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

on my case i use haproxy (for lb, 1 active, 1 standby/backup mode) and keepalived (for ip failover). on norman condition, only 1 server active, 2nd server will standby. the synchronization between server1 and server2 using mysql master-master (circular replication).

```
 192.168.1.2 \
               - 192.168.1.1 (VIP) -- 123.123.123.123 - internet
 192.168.1.3 /
```

ref:
- http://www.alexwilliams.ca/blog/2009/08/10/using-haproxy-for-mysql-failover-and-redundancy/
- http://www.neocodesoftware.com/replication/